# Solve Captcha with Python

Tags: python-3.x, api, selenium, recaptcha

I am using a Anti-Captcha Service to try bypassing the ReCAPTCHA from Google.

The result of this code is:

```
{'errorId': 0, 'status': 'ready', 'solution': {'gRecaptchaResponse': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}, 'cost': '0.00...', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'createTime': 9999999999, 'endTime': 9999999999, 'solveCount': 0, 'taskId': 11111111}
```

With the `gRecaptchaResponse` Key I can somehow bypass the Captcha, that's what I understood from the API Docs.

I tried a Network Analysis on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo but I don't get a GET-Request-Method with `gRecaptchaResponse` attribute. So I have no idea how to get this working because I don't know where or how exactly I can use the `gRecaptchaResponse` key I got from the Captcha ByPass Service.

But some Off Topic: How is it possible that this could work? I mean Google normally gives every time (F5) you try a Captcha a new Captcha token which identifies you. So for me it would be just logical to refer one token to one `gRecaptchaResponse` key. So if somebody else gets the solution for you, he can give you his `gRecaptchaResponse` result key but how is it possible that this key works for every token?

Thanks already and best regards!

```py
def solveCaptcha():
    ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = "11133331111333777"
    result = NoCaptchaTaskProxyless.NoCaptchaTaskProxyless(
        anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY
    ).captcha_handler(
        websiteURL="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo",
        websiteKey="6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-",
    )
    print(result)
solveCaptcha()
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using webdriving with Python (Selenium or similar).
You should get  the ANTICAPTCHA_KEY from your Anti-Captcha account. It gives acces to API to your Anti-Captcha credit.

I recommend you adding your ANTICAPTCHA_KEY to your environ. Execute the following command in shell or add the line to your bash file (.bashrc or similar)

```
export ANTICAPTCHA_KEY="your_key"
```

Your code could be like this:

```
import os 
from python3_anticaptcha import NoCaptchaTaskProxyless
from selenium import webdriver

ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = os.environ["ANTICAPTCHA_KEY"]

def solveCaptcha():
    result = NoCaptchaTaskProxyless.NoCaptchaTaskProxyless(
        anticaptcha_key=ANTICAPTCHA_KEY
    ).captcha_handler(
        websiteURL="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo",
        websiteKey="6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-",
    )
    return result.get("solution").get("gRecaptchaResponse")
```

First, set webdriver, get the page and execute the function to assign the response to a variable.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
captcha_response = solveCaptcha()
```

You can use the following script to make the grecaptcha response box visible, so you can see if it's working.

```
driver.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].style.display='inline'",
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="g-recaptcha-response"]'
    ),
)
```

Then execute the script to insert the response into the text box:

```
driver.execute_script(
'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = "%s"'
            % captcha_response
)
```

After that press your submit button and you'll see your success.